# Demistify Coercion in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Can somebody help me in demystifying the following expression:

```
++[[]][+[]]+[+[]]
```

**My Understanding**
Going from left to right:

- `++[[]]`: Not sure what this will evaluate to and how.
- `[+[]]`: The +[] will be executed first and the unary operator will try to convert [] to number. Hence 0. So the output of [+[]] will be [0].
- `[+[]]+[+[]]`: Which is equal to [0] + [0]. Here both the array's toString() method will be called and the output will be "00".

Basically I am not able to understand the left most expression i.e. `++[[]]`

Comment: The only real answer to this is "Carefully read the spec".

Comment: http://es5.github.io/#x11.6.1 http://es5.github.io/#x11.4.6

Comment: Why not study this for a realistic, useful example, rather than this contrivance?

Comment: javascript type casting, nothing else

Comment: I dont understand, why downvote for such a question? The answer to everything in Javascript is in the specifications. Please help me understand.

Comment: Because you should narrow this down to the specific part that you don't understand.

Comment: You should demonstrate that you have tried something, not just post it to somebody to answer same time you're on your facebook.

Comment: Thanks Oli and DontVoteMeDown for the explanation. Let me edit my post then.

Comment: Ok that seems a lot more reasonable now.

Comment: @AnupVasudeva Check if my explanation solves your confusion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
++[[]][+[]]+[+[]]
```

The expression will be broken into two as follows

- `++[[]][+[]]` and `[+[]]`

Now `[+[]]` evaluates to `[0]` (As you already understand.)

Next consider `++[[]][+[]]` equivalent to `++([[]][+[]])`:

steps(process)

- `++[[]][0]`

Now `[[]]` is an array containing a single array as its element. So `[[]][0]` evaluates to `[]` that is already allocated in memory.

Now as the 0-element array is already allocated in memory hence at the time of a mathematical operation it is converted into `0` and hence the memory location having the 0-element array when incremented using `++` operator the memory location gets the new value 1.

So `++[[]][+[]]` finally evaluates to `1`.

Now its `1+[0]` i.e. `1+[0].toString()` i.e. `1.toString()+"0"` i.e. `"1" + "0"` i.e. **`10`**.

Comment: @AnupVasudeva Even when you asked the question this was totally a **mess** to me too. But later when I tested in the console the concept was clear enough to be explained. Glad that my concept is useful. Thanx for raising this query. +1 for the question.

Answer (score 0):

`[+[]]` translates to `[0]`

`++[[]][+[]]` translates to `1`

And `1 + [0]` is equal to `"10"` in javascript

Comment: I am interested in the "how" part

Comment: Doing `+[]` makes the js engine think that you are adding 0 to an array which converts it to a number (0)

Comment: Please explain how does `++[[]][+[]]` evaluates to `1`. The rest is quite clear now.

Comment: `++` usually equated to `+1` and `0 + 1` is `1`